# geolocate current location remove previous marker

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a button that when clicked identifies the current location of the user.  Problem is, if they click the button again as their device becomes more precise to their location, another marker is added to the map.  The more they click, the more markers are created.

How can I remove/update/refresh the first instance of a marker should they click the locate current location button again?

here is my locate function:

```
function findCurrentPosition() {   
            // start the geolocation API
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                // when geolocation is available on your device, run this function
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundYou, notFound);
            } else {
                // when no geolocation is available, alert this message
                alert('Geolocation not supported or not enabled.');
            }
        }

        function foundYou(position) {
            // convert the position returned by the geolocation API to a google coordinate object
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            // then try to reverse geocode the location to return a human-readable address
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    // if the geolocation was recognized and an address was found
                    if (results[0]) {
                        // add a marker to the map on the geolocated point
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,                   
                            map: map
                        });
                        // compose a string with the address parts
                        var address = results[0].address_components[1].long_name + ' ' + results[0].address_components[0].long_name + ', ' + results[0].address_components[3].long_name
                        // set the located address to the link, show the link and add a click event handler

                            // onclick, set the geocoded address to the start-point formfield
                            $('#from').text(address);
                            $('#from').val(address);
                            // call the calcRoute function to start calculating the route        
                    }
                } else {
                    // if the address couldn't be determined, alert and error with the status message
                    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                }
            });
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: pls show code that is calling findCurrentPosition(), probably there u could adjust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code of yours is causing the problem which creates a new marker each time whenever `foundYou` method is invoked.

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: latlng,                   
                                map: map
                            });
```

Instead make declare `marker` variable outside the `foundYou` method like

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({   
                                map: map
                            });
```

and then use of [**`setPosition(latLng)`**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Marker) method to ***update*** the `marker's` position.

```
marker.setPosition(latlng);  // this will update the position of the marker
```

Comment: Great responses!  Thanks a bunch for your replies.

- the findCurrentPosition() is just fired by a button click event, so thats all there is to it.
- using the removeMarkers method doesn't seem to do anything, which is the same result as just removing the last marker.

I like Praveen's approach but it too isn't working.  I'm guessing the marker definition is not working which means the setposition will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remember the current state to disable geocoding again, because they wont have change their position when they click the button immediatly a second time :

```
// should evaluate to true if geocoder is busy
// be sure it is set before  findCurrentPosition() call
isBusy=false;

function findCurrentPosition() {   
            // start the geolocation API if its not busy
            if(!isBusy){
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    //now youre geocoder will be busy
                    isBusy = true;

                    // when geolocation is available on your device, run this function
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundYou, notFound);
                } else {
                    // when no geolocation is available, alert this message
                    alert('Geolocation not supported or not enabled.');
                }                
            }else {
                console.log("already finding");
            }

        }

        function foundYou(position) {
            // convert the position returned by the geolocation API to a google coordinate object
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            // then try to reverse geocode the location to return a human-readable address
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    // if the geolocation was recognized and an address was found
                    if (results[0]) {
                        // add a marker to the map on the geolocated point
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,                   
                            map: map
                        });
                        // compose a string with the address parts
                        var address = results[0].address_components[1].long_name + ' ' + results[0].address_components[0].long_name + ', ' + results[0].address_components[3].long_name
                        // set the located address to the link, show the link and add a click event handler

                            // onclick, set the geocoded address to the start-point formfield
                            $('#from').text(address);
                            $('#from').val(address);
                            // call the calcRoute function to start calculating the route        
                    }
                } else {
                    // if the address couldn't be determined, alert and error with the status message
                    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                }
                // Now the geoCoder finished doing what it should
                isBusy = false;

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use removeMarkers() method like below:

```
function findCurrentPosition() {   
        // start the geolocation API
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            // when geolocation is available on your device, run this function
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundYou, notFound);
        } else {
            // when no geolocation is available, alert this message
            alert('Geolocation not supported or not enabled.');
        }
    }

    function foundYou(position) {
        // convert the position returned by the geolocation API to a google coordinate object
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        // then try to reverse geocode the location to return a human-readable address
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                // if the geolocation was recognized and an address was found
                if (results[0]) {

                    //remove markers berfore creating them.
                    map.removeMarkers();

                    // add a marker to the map on the geolocated point
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,                   
                        map: map
                    });
                    // compose a string with the address parts
                    var address = results[0].address_components[1].long_name + ' ' + results[0].address_components[0].long_name + ', ' + results[0].address_components[3].long_name
                    // set the located address to the link, show the link and add a click event handler

                        // onclick, set the geocoded address to the start-point formfield
                        $('#from').text(address);
                        $('#from').val(address);
                        // call the calcRoute function to start calculating the route        
                }
            } else {
                // if the address couldn't be determined, alert and error with the status message
                alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I used Praveen's suggestion and after I fixed a missing bracket :) I now have it working as expected.  Much appreciated.  The removeMarkers didn't work for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the last marker created.

```
if(marker){
   marker.setMap(null);
   marker = '';
}
```

Insert this before create a new marker.

You should remove marker creation from foundYou function.

Comment: I guess my question to some of these responses (that I didn't get to work) is there an advantage to them opposed to the method I used instead?  (ie common practice, code flow, etc.)

Comment: @Frost common javascript practice, simpler to read code when you have to manage hundreds of code lines. Scalability! Maybe in a near future you will need to add more markers to the map. You should create a global variable array named markers and push all markers to it, with a function that do just that. Then you can call that function from any where in your code.